# Graph operation name?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

I want to form a new graph from a graph $G$ by adding a new vertex $u$ and an edge between this new vertex and one existing vertex of $G$. is there any specific name for this operation?

Is there any special name for if the original graph $G$ is a complete graph(This will be enough for me).

I know, the join and corona operations are not for a single vertex.

Comment: This operation is a special case of a "vertex splitting", which replaces a vertex $v$ with vertices $v_1$ and $v_2$, replaces each edge $uv$ with *either* $uv_1$ *or* $uv_2$, and adds the edge $v_1v_2$. That is, the existing neighbors of $v$ are partitioned into neighbors of $v_1$ and neighbors of $v_2$ (and then also $v_1$ and $v_2$ become neighbors). With the operation you describe, one of the neighbor partitions is empty. I don't know if this case has a specific name. ("Vertex sprouting", perhaps? :) Some contexts may not allow it.

Comment: I've seen the term 'augmentation' used for this, which is more general - an addition of either a) one new edge between two existing vertices or b) a new vertex and a set of edges to existing vertices